# Call a static var in another class , in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to get a static variable from a class so I do this
in file Login.h

```
 + (instancetype)setToken:(NSString *)aToken;
```

In file Login.m I do this

```
 static NSString* token;
     .......
     +(instancetype)setToken:(NSString *)aToken
     {
         token = [aToken copy];
         return aToken;
     }
```

so I can get value

```
[Login setToken:token]
```

But I don't know how to get this value in another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a getter method for that. This method will return that `static` variable value.

Add signature of that method to `Login.h` file.

```
+ (NSString *) getUniqueToken;
```

Relevant method in `Login.m` class.

```
+ (NSString *) getUniqueToken {
         return token;
}
```

As it is a class method you can direclty access with out creating object of login class.

Call above method in other controller class, It will return token string.

```
[Login getToken];
```

Comment: `token` and not `getToken` is the generally accepted form of the getter method.

Comment: Agreed! But it needs to be @property for that right?

Comment: No, setters and getters were around before `@property` was even invented.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a class getter method as well:

```
+ (void)setToken:(NSString *)token;
+ (NSString *)token;
```

However using a singleton is the preferred way of doing this, allowing you to use a `@property`.